# How to convert from world coordinates to pixel indices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 512x512x313 volume of dicom images and i have a point represented in world coordinates say (57.7475 63.4184 83.1515), how could I get the corresponding pixel coordinate of that world coordinate in Matlab??

Answer (score 1):

I hate to burst your bubble, but what you are asking for is impossible.  The only way that I can think of where you are able to get a correspondence between real-world co-ordinates and pixel co-ordinates is if you **calibrate the camera** that was used to capture the images.  Once you know the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters, you then have a transformation matrix that can map real-world co-ordinates to pixel co-ordinates.

I'm assuming you don't have calibration information for your camera, and so an alternative approach would be knowing which pixels in your image map to which real-world co-ordinates.  You would need to know point correspondences between those points that map between the real-world and to your image.  Once you know this, you would then compute the camera transformation matrix through least-squares and then you would use this matrix to determine which points map from the real-world to your image.

Unless you have pixel correspondences to each of your real-world co-ordinates, it is impossible to do what you're asking.

FWIW, if you want to see the procedure on how to obtain the transformation matrix, check out these notes: http://www.peterhillman.org.uk/downloads/whitepapers/calibration.pdf.  This was a great starting point for me when I started learning about camera calibration.  Take a look at Section #5 (Page #8), as this is what I believe you are looking for.... but you will need to have correspondences between the real-world co-ordinates and your image.

Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I don't have camera calibration, as the images are captured by a CT medical device. I have .mhd file for the volume and someone told me lately that I should get the origin and orientation of the images to know how to transform between world and pixel coordinates, but I still don't know or find how to do that through matlab...do u have any idea about such functions?

Comment: @NohaSeada - To get the orientation and origin, you need to calibrate your camera :) This is probably what they were referring to.  However, since you can't calibrate, then you need to have correspondences that map from pixels to real-world co-ordinates.  If you have a bunch of points where you know where they are in pixels and those same points in the real-world, then you can find the transformation matrix.  You can either use the above approach, or you can try **image registration**.  Try this link too: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/registering-multimodal-mri-images.html