# how convert pixel to mm for a mat file using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, pixel

I was wondering how can I convert pixel to the mm while my image is a mat file (uint 8). For example, I have a kernel size of 11 * 11 and another one a kernel size of 21 * 21, and I need to know what is equivalent of these sizes in mm?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188495/

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it is not helpful in my case, as I don't have dicom image.

Comment: You should read the answer. DICOM is irrelevant as this is just a storage format. The main issue discussed there is the conversion between pixels and physical units, which is the same problem as yours. Long story short - unless you have some calibration, there's not much you can do.